Damping of a Lagrangian System in 3D
I have a Lagrangian, that describes a Pendulum hanging on a spinning disk in 3D. It looks like this:
$$
L(p,\lambda, t) = \frac 12m\|\dot p\|^2-m g p\cdot\hat k+\lambda(\|p-q\|^2-l^2)
$$
with $p$ and $q$ being:
$$
\cases{
q=r(\hat i \cos(\omega t) + \hat j\sin(\omega t))+q_0 \hat k\\
p = (x(t),y(t),z(t))
}\ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
If I now want to add viscous damping which is defined with:
$$
f = c \cdot \dot{p}
$$
How do I do that, I have tried to just substract it like this:
$$
L(p,\lambda, t) = \frac 12m\|\dot p\|^2-m g p\cdot\hat k+\lambda(\|p-q\|^2-l^2)- c \cdot \dot{p}
$$
But when trying to calculate the Euler lagrangian, $c$ as the coefficient disapears through the derivative here:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot p}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial p}=0
$$
Does this mean it has no effect or is there something wrong with the damping term?
How would you add the damping to the Lagrangian?

If you have dissipatrice forces the EL equations must be modified to include these forces explicitly.  See [this post or this post.

So from one of the posts I would assume, that the Lagrangian looks like this: $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot p}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial p} = c \cdot \dot{p} $$
